# Beyond Compare 3 Make Case Sensitive within Scripts

Tags: beyondcompare3

I have already knew that we can call BC3 in the windows cmd with the format "BCompare.exe /silent @scrip_file.txt txt1 txt2 output.html". So I would like to know, how to write the script_file.txt, which make the comparison case sensitive, for example shows the difference between "apple" in txt1 and "APPLE" in txt2?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible to make a comparison case sensitive using a scripting command. Instead, edit the default session settings in the GUI, which will affect scripts.

To edit default Text Compare session settings in Beyond Compare 3:

1. Run Beyond Compare 3.
2. In the **Saved sessions** list, expand **Edit session defaults**.
3. Select **Text Compare**.
4. Go to the **Importance** tab.
5. Check **Character case** to make it important, then **Save**.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for replying me for the both sites, I have tried your method it works for one comparison session, but since we have lots of comparison tasks at one time, is there exist a method which allow to call this setting automatically from the cmd?

Comment: It isn't possible to configure the setting with a scripting command, it can only be set by editing session settings in the GUI.